# php string to associative array with value=>value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have string

```
$string1 = `a,b,c,d`;

$array1 = explode(',', $string1);
```

Gives me :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'a',
    (int) 1 => 'b',
    (int) 2 => 'c'
    (int) 3 => 'd'
)
```

But I want it to be like this

```
array(
        'a' => 'a',
        'b' => 'b',
        'c' => 'c'
        'd' => 'd'
    )
```

How do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create a new array after exploding...

```
$tmp_arr = explode(',', $string1);
$array1 = array();
foreach ($tmp_arr as $item){
    $array1[$item] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) function

```
$string = `a,b,c,d`;
$array = explode(',', $string);    
var_dump(array_combine($array, $array));
```

Comment: This is probably a better solution then mine above.